# word interop changing Formatting Restriction within protect document

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

we have an Office Automation written in c# to include data in a specific Section. After we insert the data in the Word document we protect the section where we added the Data. To do this we use the following code =>

```
WordEngine wemain =...
...            
wemain.ProtectDocument(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyFormFields, bFalse, szPassword, bFalse, bFalse);
```

**All this works fine.**

Problem now is that the Customer wants to be able to turn the Line Numbering on and off in the protected File. For this I saw that Microsoft offers Settings in the Restrict Editing Dialog => Formatting Restriction.

[image]

Does anyone knows how I can change this via interop?

Best Regards

Michael